# Javascript random addition and subtraction generator that prevents running negative numbers

Tags: javascript, random

On my miniquest to improve my Javascript, I'm building some quick games that are designed to not take long to code. I have a timed add/sub like so:

```
function flash() {

      size = 3
      rand1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 201) - 100);
      rand2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 201) - 100);
      randMax = Math.max(rand1,rand2)
      randMin = Math.min(rand1,rand2)

      if (randMax - randMin > 0 ){
      if (i < size) {

        timer = setTimeout(function() {
          display.value = randMax;
          answer += randMax;
          setTimeout(function() {
            display.value = '';
          }, 1000);
          flash();
        }, 5000);
        i++;
      }} else {
        clearTimeout(timer);
      }
    }
```

To prevent a negative answer for both the final result AND any on-the-fly result, is the only way to populate the answer in an array beforehand, and compare max/min as we iterate through the array? (eg. [1,-3,4,1,8] would fail 'always >= 0' parameters, while [1,-1,3,-2,4] would pass. If so/if not, how would you approach it?

**Update:**
So far, this is what I have. I've solved the negatives issue by constructing an array w/certain parameters. I think now I've got an infinite for loop..

```
var display = document.getElementById("display-me");
var answer, i, timer;
display.value = "";

function getRandom(min, max) {
  var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max + 1 - min)) + min;
  return random;
}

var rows = 5;
var rangeFrom = 0;
var rangeTo = 20;
var numbers = [];

function flash() {
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    var val;
    val = getRandom(rangeFrom, rangeTo);

    if (sum > val && getRandom(0, 2) < 1) {
      val = -val;
    }
    sum += val;
    numbers.push(val);

    if (i < rows) {
      timer = setTimeout(function() {
        display.value = 5;
        answer += 5;
        setTimeout(function() {
          display.value = "";
        }, 1000);
        flash();
      }, 1000);
      i++;
    } else {
      clearTimeout(timer);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What "results" are you referring to?  In what variable should we be looking at these results?  Also, I'd recommend using a linter while coding, and possibly running this by https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ when you're done-- I see a few obvious issues and a few potential issues...

Comment: w/r to results, I'm talking about the 'answer' variable

Comment: *:...eg. [1,-3,4,1,8] would fail 'always >= 0' parameters, while [1,-1,3,-2,4] would pass. "* Errr...whut?

Comment: @zer00ne whenever a new item flashes, the result must be >=0. So, if the first item that flashes is neg, the program fails; if item+item2 is neg, program fails. But, if the sum of the iterable is >= 0, AND item1 is >=0, AND itemN+ nextItem is >= 0, program passes.

Answer (score -2):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to know how to reliably generate two random numbers between -100 and 100 where the sum of those two numbers is always >= 0. You can do that like this:

```js
var rand1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 201) - 100);
var rand2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 201) - 100);

if(Math.abs(rand1) > Math.abs(rand2)) rand1 = Math.abs(rand1);
else if(Math.abs(rand2) > Math.abs(rand1)) rand2 = Math.abs(rand2);

console.log(rand1, rand2);
```

The key is to make sure the number that's furthest away from zero is a positive number. You can also simplify the randomness here with [randojs.com](https://randojs.com) just to make it more readable. That's what I like to do:

```js
var rand1 = rando(-100, 100);
var rand2 = rando(-100, 100);

if(Math.abs(rand1) > Math.abs(rand2)) rand1 = Math.abs(rand1);
else if(Math.abs(rand2) > Math.abs(rand1)) rand2 = Math.abs(rand2);

console.log(rand1, rand2);
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

Randojs is pretty self-explanatory, but check out the website if you need an explanation.

Comment: thx for the suggestions, but some parameters are still not covered. For instance, if the first two random numbers were -30, and -40, rand1 would not change from -30 to 30, and thus the first number in the sequence would be negative. This error could appear in any further loops as well..